# How to define variable which we do not want as state without useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do we define a variable which should not be state or props. I found a solution by using `useRef` which can store mutable value. But I want to know if there is another solution like

```
let timerStart = new Date()

const handlePlay = () => {
    console.log('play', timerStart)
    timerStart = new Date()
}

const handlePause = () => {
    console.log('pause',timerStart)
}
```

and output is

```
play Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
App.js:199 pause Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
App.js:189 play Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
App.js:199 pause Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
App.js:189 play Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

Why the value is not updating here?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `useRef`? It's literally what it's designed for. To store a mutable value that doesn't directly affect rendering and thus shouldn't be in state.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to think of react components as 'not-very-smart snapshots'. They need to be told explicitly about the variables being used. As Jayce444 mentioned, this is what UseRef is for, if your're looking for more sophisticated state management solutions have a look at React Context, Redux or Recoil.